# Need to change Global List element name

Tags: tfs

We have a globalist name "Reported in Test" and i want the name in the global list to be changed to "Reported In Test" the change is the letter " i " i am trying to make it Upper case. But when i make the change  and import the global list it gets imported successfully but the new name is not reflecting . I tried many times but no use. Can any one help ?

[Screen Shot of the value to be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X0pG.png)

﻿

I want the change like "MessageNet_ReportedInRelease"

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? Rather than modify the process template, you could use a tag to capture this information if you're using a version of TFS that supports tags.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your scenario on my side, even destroying global list MessageNet_ReportedinRelease with `witadmin destroygloballist` command, and importing golbal list MessageNet_ReportedInRelease, I still get global list MessageNet_ReportedinRelease. You can try to submit feedback at website https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/.

As an alternative, you may change the MessageNet_ReportedinRelease to **MessageNet-ReportedInRelease**(change from _ to -), in this way, TFS treat it as a new global list, then you will see a Upper case "i".